# Function is invoking but not entering {}

Tags: javascript, angular, express

From 1 .js file to another, I invoke the below code.  None of the console log's are executed and the next statement executed is below this code.

```
         Picks.getSome ( req , ( err , somethingElse )  => {
                    console.log("log this" + JSON.stringify(somethingElse));                    
                    if (!err){
                        console.log ("what happened" + err)
                    }
         });
```

getSome is invoked and executed.  I'm able to log the correct output from Mongo.  Why doesn't this code enter into the function?

getSome looks like this and all of the console logs print the correct result.  I get JSON from mongo and see it's well-formed and printing.

```
exports.getSome = (req) => {
    var addy = req.body.email;
    Some.findOne({ 'email' :  addy }, (err, somethingElse) => {
        if (err) {
            return ({ 'msg': err });
        } 

        console.log("made the query " + JSON.stringify(somethingElse)); 
        return somethingElse  ;
    });
};
```

Comment: getSome is a function that only takes one parameter, why do you have two?

Comment: I thought it's passing the parameter req and the err and somethingElse are projected parameters.The exported getSome function is invoked.The code after the => isn't getting invoked. @hogan

Comment: Is the issue multiple promises so the code isn't waiting for the 2nd promise to complete?